# Polymer iron-form Chrome won't ask to store password

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, polymer-1.0

I'm using Polymer and have a login form as the home page. It looks roughly like this:

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="POST" action="#">
    <paper-input id="email" name="email">
    <paper-input id="password" name="password">
    <paper-button id="loginButton" on-tap="_login">Login</paper-button>
</form>

<script>
_login: function()
{
    if (this.$.form.validate())
    {
        var params = this.$.form.serialize();

        // Valid form
        Ajax.post("LoginService", params, function(result)
        {
            if (result)
            {
                // Valid login
                location.reload();
            }
            else
            {
                // Invalid form
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // Not valid
    }
}
</script>
```

Ajax.post being a convenience method for a jquery ajax call. With this setup, Firefox will correctly ask the user if they would like to store their password and it refreshes the page. From what I've read, this is because Firefox asks on submit, whereas Chrome asks once the new page is loaded.

I've tried changing the iron-form to a form, but that seems to cause the "re-submit post" warning when refreshing the page/logging out and it doesn't make the prompt show anyway.

I've tried building a form and appending the fields to that, but that doesn't work.

I've tried simply "submitting" the iron form, but the page doesn't reload due to the ajax nature of iron-form. Adding a manual reload to this doesn't work.

So, based on what I have here, is there anyway to get Chrome to ask to store the password?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. This whole area of saving a password is a mess. Ideal would be some general API supported by browsers. I'm using Firebase so I handle the data submission myself. Did you manage to solve it somehow? Thanks